# jQuery UI setup 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I just downloaded jQuery UI but when I downloaded it it came with a bunch of different files & I'm confused if I need to use them all & where I need to put them.

I have:

css/
development-bundle/
js/
index.html

I copied the folder inside the "css" dir & put it in my local css folder.. this seemed to contain the CSS & images for the theme I downloaded with it. I then copied the "jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" file from the "js" dir & put it inside my local js dir; however now I'm wondering do I need to copy stuff from the "development-bundle" folder & if so what?

It contains..

demos
docs/
external/
themes/
ui/
misc text files
jquery-1.5.1.js

Only stuff that looks like I might need is from the "external" dir which has a few js files in there & maybe the "themes" dir.... but I thought this was already covered previously? Also..... the files inside the "ui" directory appear to be all the related js files to what I selected for my custom bundle download + another "jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.js" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the js and css folders in order to use jQueryUI.  The development folder is used more for demos and trying things out.  It has each plugin in a separate file to allow you to pick and choose features.  So, just use the js and css folders and import the files in there to your HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have the file "jquery.effects.blind.min.js" as a separate file inside the dev folder, if I want to use this in my page do I need to include this separately as well or is it already included within the main js file I will be including?

Comment: It will probably be in the main js file.  But, it just depends on how you built the download, as jQueryUI lets you build a custom download.  You could always try using the functionality without including the file and see if it works, but my guess is that it's already there.

Comment: No problem! Hope you have fun with it all!